# In Objective-C (and Swift) are weak properties thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, swift, thread-safety, weak-references

When they are being nil'd out because the last strong reference is gone, can you have a problem if that occurs on another thread?  And if so, does using atomic correct for that?  Since I believe Swift doesn't have atomics, what is required for a thread-safe weak property there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`weak` is part of ARC, and is promised to be atomic by Clang in the way you're describing. See particularly section [4.2 Semantics](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics) in the Automatic Reference Counting documentation for Clang.

Of specific interest for this are these sections (emphasis added):

#### Reading

> For __weak objects, the current pointee is retained and then released at the end of the current full-expression. **This must execute atomically with respect to assignments and to the final release of the pointee.**

#### Assignment

> For __weak objects, the lvalue is updated to point to the new pointee, unless the new pointee is an object currently undergoing deallocation, in which case the lvalue is updated to a null pointer. **This must execute atomically with respect to other assignments to the object, to reads from the object, and to the final release of the new pointee.**

Note that many other operations are not atomic, in particular strong assignments (for example, assigning a strong property on two different threads). But the retain counting itself is thread safe, which is really the piece you're worried about here. You are free to retain and release objects on any thread, and the retain count at the end will be correct, including "implicit" releases due to `weak` assignment. It's all the direct result of the following:

- [`objc_retain`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id68) is defined to be "exactly as if the object had been sent the `retain` message."
- "Object allocation and retain count functions" are [explicitly thread-safe](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html).

The upshot of all of this is that, unlike most parts of Cocoa, reference counting is almost always going to be safely handled across threads.

Comment: As always, note that *thread safety* refers to whether or not the behavior is defined in the multithreaded case.   It does not guarantee *data integrity* in the multi threaded case.

Answer (score 0):

Almost nothing in Swift is intrinsically thread safe — not references, not weak references, not arrays, not strings, nor any other mutable value.

If you want write/read or write/write access to anything from two threads, you must use locks to ensure safety.

https://medium.com/@mohit.bhalla/thread-safety-in-ios-swift-7b75df1d2ba6

This link should help!

Comment: What about Objective-C's @property (weak, atomic)?

Comment: `weak` is a pretty big exception to this general rule (which is correct). Clang promises weak reads and assignments are atomic.

Comment: I agree with @spentag, `weak` references are not thread-safe in swift. https://forums.swift.org/t/thread-safety-of-weak-properties/422